# Como visualisar imagenes .tif?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, serverless

Quiero leer una imagen .tif en mi aplicación de react pero no me deja.

Envio mi imagen .tif desde mi serverless de la siguiente manera:

```
const result = await controll.getImage(`private/${imgFolder}/${decodeURI(key)}`)
result.Body.transformToByteArray().then(respo => {
    resolve({
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        statusCode: 200,
        isBase64Encoded: true,
        body: Buffer.from(respo, 'binary').toString('base64')
    })
})
```

Y desde mi frontend sis se recive la imagen pero al momento de cargarla me da error, la forma en que la cargo es la siguiente:

```
axios.get(`/image/${code}`
    , {
        responseType: 'blob'
    }
).then(resp => {
    setImgSoruce(URL.createObjectURL(resp.data))
}).catch(err => {
    setImgSoruce(defImg)
})
```

Donde imgSource, lo que va en mi etiqueta img, entonces no se si este formato se maneja de una formama diferente

Comment: Las imágenes soportadas dependen del navegador, aun que en el último tiempo se ha convergido en un estándar común, donde `.tif` no tiene soporte. Mas información en https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types